# Popular Spinner com Banco de dados SQLite -

Tags: android, sqlite, spinners

Tenho a seguinte tabela no banco de dados:

```
CREATE TABLE turma(_id integer primary key autoincrement, nome varchar(20))
```

Preciso preencher uma SPINNER com estes dados, de forma que seja visualizado o NOME da turma mas que na verdade quando o usuário escolher o nome da turma fique assiciado o _id da turma.

Comment: Neste link:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/342927/popular-spinner-com-dados-do-sqlite
Fiz a mesma pergunta pois apliquei os conceitos e não deu certo, agradeço se ajudarem

Answer (score 5):

Crie uma classe para representar uma *turma*:

```
public class Turma {

    private String nome;
    private int id;

    public Turma(int id, String nome){
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return nome;
    }
}
```

O método que obtém as turmas do banco deverá retornar um `ArrayList<Turma>`:

```
public ArrayList<Turma> getTurmas(){
    ArrayList<Turma> turmas = new ArrayList<Turma>();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("turma", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String nome = cursor.getString(1);
            Turma turma = new Turma(id, nome);
            turmas.add(turma);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return turmas;
}
```

Onde `db` é uma instância de *SQLiteDatabase* obtida através do método `getReadableDatabase()` da sua classe herdada de *SQLiteOpenHelper*

Use esse *ArrayList* na construção do *adapter*:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, turmasArray);
```

O *adapter* usará o método `toString()` da classe *Turma* para obter a *string* que aparecerá no *Spinner*.

Pode obter a turma selecionada no *Spinner* desta forma:

```
Turma turmaSelecionada = ((Turma)spinner.getSelectedItem());
```

Comment: Como faria para jogar do Cursor para um ArrayAdapter do tipo Turma?

Comment: Veja a edição à resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que você tenha encapsulado estas informações em um Objeto:

Exemplo:

```
class Turma {
    private Integer id;
    private String nome;
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Tendo isto, vamos criar um `Adapter` personalizado para popular o `Spinner` :

```
class TurmaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Turma>{

    public TurmaAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.spinner_adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(null == convertView){
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.spinner_adapter, parent, false);
        }
        //Pegamos a turma...
        final Turma item = getItem(position);
        // Adicionamos a turma a Tag da View...
        convertView.setTag(item);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

Agora vamos configurar o `OnItemSelectedListener` :

```
     AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener itemSelectedListener  =new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 

                // Vamos pegar o a Turma 
                final Turma turma =  Turma.class.cast(view.getTag());
               // Aqui voce poderá associar a turma! 
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        };

 meuSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(itemSelectedListener);
```